# Yahoo Finance API from date - to date query

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I would like to get a few days of historical data.  The following link works but seems to be a little weird. In this example I would like to get data from May 4, 2016 to May 6, 2016. I guess the Yahoo API value for the month is 0-11 and not 1-12. Seems to make sense anyway.

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=05&b=04&c=2016&d=05&e=06&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

This doesn't work.

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=04&b=04&c=2016&d=05&e=06&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

This returns the exact dates I want

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=03&b=04&c=2016&d=05&e=06&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

This returns the days from April 4,2016 to May 6, 2016.

Comment: You don't need any code. The query is HTTP so you can do it in any browser.

Comment: The question is related to how the Yahoo finance API works.

Answer (score 0):

The params are:

```
a= Start month - 1
b=day
c=year

d= End month - 1
e=day
f=year
```

Where start <= end